# How does the Gameboy Link Cable work?

Tags: emulation, game-boy

I've been looking into implementing Gameboy Link Cable compatibility into Bizhawk (which does not support it yet) using Lua. The problem is that I can't find any mention of how it works online.

I want to know how I can modify the gameboy's memory in order to emulate link cable behavior. Nothing on the [Serial Data Transfer (Link Cable)](https://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/Serial_Data_Transfer_(Link_Cable)) page was helpful.

How does the Gameboy know that it's being linked? What memory addresses does it utilize?
What specific part of memory tells the Gameboy that no link cable is connected? IE where does the Gameboy check before say "no link cable is connected"

Comment: https://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/Serial_Data_Transfer_(Link_Cable) might be useful

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll need to manipulate the memory address `0xFF02`, and shift the data (MSB first) into `0xFF01`, as stated below. If there is no cable - ergo, no gameboy connected - then `0xFF` is received, in `0xFF01`.

From [Serial Data Transfer (Link Cable)](https://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/Serial_Data_Transfer_(Link_Cable))

> Communication between two Gameboys happens one byte at a time. One
>   Gameboy acts as the master, uses its internal clock, and thus controls
>   when the exchange happens. The other one uses an external clock (i.e.,
>   the one inside the other Gameboy) and has no control over when the
>   transfer happens. If it hasn't gotten around to loading up the next
>   data byte at the time the transfer begins, the last one will go out
>   again. Alternately, if it's ready to send the next byte but the last
>   one hasn't gone out yet, it has no choice but to wait.
>
> #### FF01 - SB - Serial transfer data (R/W)
>
> Before a transfer, it holds the next byte that will go out. During a
>   transfer, it has a blend of the outgoing and incoming bytes. Each
>   cycle, the leftmost bit is shifted out (and over the wire) and the
>   incoming bit is shifted in from the other side:
>
> ```
> o7 o6 o5 o4 o3 o2 o1 o0
> o6 o5 o4 o3 o2 o1 o0 i7
> o5 o4 o3 o2 o1 o0 i7 i6
> o4 o3 o2 o1 o0 i7 i6 i5
> o3 o2 o1 o0 i7 i6 i5 i4
> o2 o1 o0 i7 i6 i5 i4 i3
> o1 o0 i7 i6 i5 i4 i3 i2
> o0 i7 i6 i5 i4 i3 i2 i1
> i7 i6 i5 i4 i3 i2 i1 i0
> ```
>
> #### FF02 - SC - Serial Transfer Control (R/W)
>
> ```
>  Bit 7 - Transfer Start Flag (0=No transfer is in progress or requested, 1=Transfer in progress, or requested)
>  Bit 1 - Clock Speed (0=Normal, 1=Fast) ** CGB Mode Only **
>  Bit 0 - Shift Clock (0=External Clock, 1=Internal Clock)
> ```
>
> The gameboy acting as master will load up a data byte in SB and then
>   set SC to 0x81 (Transfer requested, use internal clock). It will be
>   notified that the transfer is complete in two ways: SC's Bit 7 will be
>   cleared (i.e., SC will be set up 0x01), and also the Serial Interrupt
>   handler will be called (i.e., the CPU will jump to 0x0058). The other
>   gameboy will load up a data byte and can optionally set SC's Bit 7
>   (i.e., SC=0x80). Regardless of whether or not it has done this, if and
>   when the master gameboy wants to conduct a transfer, it will happen
>   (pulling whatever happens to be in SB at that time). The passive
>   gameboy will have its serial interrupt handler called at the end of
>   the transfer, and if it bothered to set SC's Bit 7, it will be
>   cleared.

...

> During a transfer, a byte is shifted in at the same time that a byte
>   is shifted out. The rate of the shift is determined by whether the
>   clock source is internal or external. The most significant bit is
>   shifted in and out first. When the internal clock is selected, it
>   drives the clock pin on the game link port and it stays high when not
>   used. During a transfer it will go low eight times to clock in/out
>   each bit.
>
> The state of the last bit shifted out determines the state of the
>   output line until another transfer takes place.
>
> If a serial transfer with internal clock is performed and no external
>   GameBoy is present, a value of $FF will be received in the transfer.
>   The following code initiates the process of shifting $75 out the
>   serial port and a byte to be shifted into $FF01:
>
> ```
> ld   a,$75
> ld  ($FF01),a
> ld   a,$81
> ld  ($FF02),a
> ```
>
> The Game Boy does not support wake-on-LAN. Completion of an externally
>   clocked serial transfer does not exit STOP mode.

This link, [Everything You Always Wanted To Know About GAMEBOY](http://www.devrs.com/gb/files/gbspec.txt), also shows the memory map (indicating the interrupt locations and the comms bytes) which will clarify the data from the first link:

> ```
> GB General Memory Map*
>
> ---------------------
>
>   Interrupt Enable Register
>
>  --------------------------- FFFF
>
>   Internal RAM
>
>  --------------------------- FF80
>
>   Empty but unusable for I/O
>
>  --------------------------- FF4C
>
>   I/O ports
>
>  --------------------------- FF00
>
>   Empty but unusable for I/O
>
>  --------------------------- FEA0
>
>   Sprite Attrib Memory (OAM)
>
>  --------------------------- FE00
>
>   Echo of 8kB Internal RAM
>
>  --------------------------- E000
>
>   8kB Internal RAM
>
>  --------------------------- C000
>
>   8kB switchable RAM bank
>
>  --------------------------- A000
>
>   8kB Video RAM
>
>  --------------------------- 8000
>
>   32kB Cartridge
>
>  --------------------------- 0000
>
>
>
>
>
>  * NOTE: b = bit, B = byte
> ```

Comment: This looks like [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface) basically.

Comment: @Melebius Oh, it probably is just a vendor-specific implementation of it. A lot of communication protocols look alike, are based on one another, developed concurrently, or any other reason to make them similar to others out there.

Comment: @hobbs OK, my comment intended to say: If you have an SPI library available, you’ll be probably able to utilize it here.

Comment: FWIW I noticed that the diagram in the SPI article @Melebius linked to exactly matches the Gameboy protocol. (i.e a distributed ring buffer)

Answer (score 14):

*Note, this is a supplement to Greenonline's answer.*

Instead of emulating the bitwise transfer I would just emulate the bytewise transfer.

If some game depends on the transmission time, you need to emulate this period for the reset of bit 7 of SC. When exactly in this period you transfer the bytes doesn't matter.

If some game depends on the bitwise transfer, think about if it's worth to support it. But I'll be right astonished if such a game exists.

A shortly described (and perhaps erroneous) abstract algorithm might be:

```
forever
    if SC.7 becomes 1 then
        if SC.0 = 1 then
            # You are a master device.
            send(SB)
            SB = receive() # clears "received"
            SC.7 = 0
    if received() then
        # You are a slave device.
        send(SB)
        SB = receive() # fetch received byte
        SC.7 = 0
```

You still have to think about what happens if two masters are connected. I have no idea what happens on the hardware.

Connecting two slaves is no problem. Bytes will not be exchanged and SC.7 will remain set.

BTW, it's all in the quoted description! It "just" needs to be translated in behaviour.

Comment: "Instead of emulating the bitwise transfer I would just emulate the bytewise transfer." ?

Comment: The bitwise transfer is timed by the internal or external shift clock. The transfer happens **bit by bit** one at a clock cycle. But presumably all games watch only SC.7 which will be reset after the full **byte** was transferred. So it will save a lot of work and emulation time by **not** emulating bitwise transfers.

Comment: Oh! I read too quickly and didn't noticed that it was *bit*wise vs *byte*wise, and thought there was a typo. My bad.

Comment: I'd be more tempted to calculate it just-in-time, which collapses into the whole-byte case if software doesn't read or write while a shift is ongoing, but could also give the correct result if it does. E.g. a read is `bits = (now - start) / period` bits in, so the read result is `(local << bits) | (remote >> (8 - bits))`. There's no difference to the need to count time properly to trigger an interrupt, and you could treat writes correctly with just an extra piece of storage and a subtraction, i.e. `(local << (bits - write_time)) | ...`.